# Codeigniter loading a library in a static function

Tags: php, model, codeigniter-2

I have a static function in my users_model, called isLoggedin(), that needs a library I made. I can't get it to load! It's in the libraries folder under the name SessionsHelper.php and has a class SessionsHelper in it(unsurprising I know). I tried loading it in the static function with `$this->load->library('SessionsHelper')` only to find that I can't use $this in a static function. Then I tried to load it using `require_once '../libraries/SessionsHelper.php'` which didn't work, then I tried the autoloader, which didn't work either.... so here's the function.

```
public static function isLoggedin() {
        if (SessionsHelper::get('id') != '' && SessionsHelper::get('id') >= 0) { // TODO add logic to differentiate between user/admin
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I just need to be able to use the library! Please any help would be very appreciative!

EDIT:
The controller is:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    public function login(){
        $this->load->model('users_model');

        if($this->users_model->isLoggedin()){
            redirect($this->config->base_url);
        }

        $data['info'] = $this->users_model->login('slavigne@uark.edu', 'abcdefg');

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->load->library('SessionHelper');
        SessionsHelper::destroy();
    }
}
```

the model is:

```
class users_model extends CI_Model{
    public function users_model(){
            parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function hash($password, $salt) {
//this code works no problem! but it's private you know?
    }

    public static function isLoggedin() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('SessionsHelper');
        if (SessionsHelper::get('id') != '' && SessionsHelper::get('id') >= 0) { // TODO add logic to differentiate between user/admin
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($email, $password){
        $this->load->library('SessionHelper');
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email));
        $result = $query->result();
        if($result[0]->password == $this->hash($password, $result[0]->salt)){
            //error_log("Pass matched!");
            SessionHelper::set('id', $result[0]->id);
        }        
        return $result[0];
    }
}
```

the library is and is in application/libraries/Sessinshelper.php:

```
class Sessionshelper {
        public function __construct() {      
    }

    public static function start() {
        if (!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public static function set($fld, $val) {
        self::start();
        $_SESSION[$fld] = $val;
    }

    public static function un_set($fld) {
        self::start();
        unset($_SESSION[$fld]);
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        if (session_id() != "" || isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
        }
        session_unset();
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    }

    public static function get($fld) {
        self::start();
        if (isset($_SESSION[$fld])) {
            return $_SESSION[$fld];
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can shorten the isLoggedIn() function to `return (SessionsHelper::get('id') != '' && SessionsHelper::get('id') >= 0)`. Also, protecting your passwords shouldn't depend on your hashing algorithm but on the strength of the algorithm. You didn't try to roll your own crypto, did you?

Answer (score 1):

You can load any library in a static context by loading the *globally accessible* CodeIgniter instance with `get_instance`, resulting in:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('SessionHelper');
```

But static methods are usually considered by the community as hardly testable and design smells especially when using a framework like CodeIgniter which lets you avoid it.

Comment: But If I don't then if I need to use that method then I have to load the whole class again right?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification, if you have loaded the class once in the action method then you are fine until the method's block ends.

Comment: Yes, but what about a different case where I need to use this function and I haven't loaded the model before?

Comment: That didn't work, it still says, Unable to load the requested class: sessionhelper

Comment: @Samuraisoulification, have you correctly capitalized `SessionHelper`? are you sure the file is correctly capitalized? Are you sure the class name is correctly capitalized? Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Not really, I had the file name as SessionsHelper.php and teh class as SessionsHelper. I also tried changing the file name to all lowercase. Then since even though I had load->library('SessionsHelper)[triple checked this part] the error said unable to load sessionloader, without an s. so I tried to change it the sessionhelper.php with no s, then it asked for sessionshelper.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification, may you [paste](http://pastebin.com) the entire code of the controller and action you are running?